# Queries running on snapshot database that causes high redo queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

I am trying to troubleshoot mirroring issue where we are getting threshold exceeded for unrestored log too high on mirror server.

On the mirror server we have database snapshot created for the database participating in database mirroring . Now for past week we are observing that counter high redo queue goes on increasing rapidly to 30-40 GB and after 4-5 hours start normalizing.

While troubleshooting i came to know that users are querying on snapshot database. Many of them running for last 2-3 hours and some for hour and some for mins. But i have seen queries which are running for over 5 hours kept running and this redo queue starts lowering down may be because of other queries getting completed.

How can i identify or troubleshoot further to find that culprit set of queries which are actually causing unrestored log to go that high

Update@ Database mirroring is in SYNC mode